# Need to add another product code in magento 2 other than Sku

Tags: magento2, product

We use the Sku number for products but I need to add company ref# too other than the sku#, where and what is the best way to add this number which is not going to be visible to customer frontend. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest you to create a product attribute
2. Ensure you assign it to the correct attribute set
3. Store your product value in the newly created attribute